# How to summarize a list of combination

Tags: r, list, cluster-analysis

I have a list of 2 elements' combination like below.

```
cbnl <- list(
  c("A", "B"), c("B", "A"), c("C", "D"), c("E", "D"), c("F", "G"), c("H", "I"),
  c("J", "K"), c("I", "H"), c("K", "J"), c("G", "F"), c("D", "C"), c("E", "C"),
  c("D", "E"), c("C", "E")
)
```

I'd like to summarize above list. Expected result is like below list. Order of element in a vector doesn't matter here.

```
[[1]]
[1] "A" "B"

[[2]]
[1] "C" "D" "E"

[[3]]
[1] "F" "G"

[[4]]
[1] "H" "I"

[[5]]
[1] "J" "K"
```

(Rule 1) {A, B} is equivalent to {B, A}. To correspond this I think I can do this.

```
cbnl <- unique(lapply(cbnl, function(i) { sort(i) }))
```

(Rule 2) {A, B}, {B, C} (One of element is common) then take a union of two sets. It results {A, B, C}. I don't have clear nice idea to do this.

Any efficient way to do this?

Comment: Yes, it's essentially the same. From graph theory view point this can be thought as connections of nodes. Thank you for your point.

Comment: I thought [Merging Listed Vectors that share Elements in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49101813/merging-listed-vectors-that-share-elements-in-r) is essentially the same, but R code doesn't work for this case. The answer here may not work for a list of numeric vectors.....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know this answer is more like a traditional programming rather than "R like" but it solves the issue.

```
cbnl <- unique(lapply(cbnl, sort))

i <- 1
count <- 1
out <- list()

while (i <= length(cbnl) - 1) {
  if (sum(cbnl[[i]] %in% cbnl[[i + 1]]) == 0) {
    out[[count]] <- cbnl[[i]]
    } else {
      out[[count]] <- sort(unique(c(cbnl[[i]], cbnl[[i + 1]])))
      i <- i + 1        
    }
  count <- count + 1
  i <- i + 1 
}

out
```

gives,

```
[[1]]
[1] "A" "B"

[[2]]
[1] "C" "D" "E"

[[3]]
[1] "F" "G"

[[4]]
[1] "H" "I"

[[5]]
[1] "J" "K"
```

Comment: Great. Thank you for the answer. I got a expected result.

Answer (score 6):

You can try the following `igraph` option

```
library(igraph)

graph_from_data_frame(do.call(rbind, cbnl)) %>%
  components() %>%
  membership() %>%
  stack() %>%
  with(., split(as.character(ind), values))
```

which gives

```
$`1`
[1] "A" "B"

$`2`
[1] "C" "E" "D"

$`3`
[1] "F" "G"

$`4`
[1] "H" "I"

$`5`
[1] "J" "K"
```

---

A shorter one

```
graph_from_data_frame(do.call(rbind, cbnl)) %>%
  decompose() %>%
  Map(function(x) names(V(x)), .)
```

which gives

```
[[1]]
[1] "A" "B"

[[2]]
[1] "C" "E" "D"

[[3]]
[1] "F" "G"

[[4]]
[1] "H" "I"

[[5]]
[1] "J" "K"
```

Comment: Oh, this is shorter command. Expected result comes out.

Comment: @kabocha you can find a shorter one in my update

Comment: Thank you. Very simple code!!

Comment: The funny thing is that few months ago I was searching for an algorithm / function to find records linked in this way and I remember I couldn't find an appropriate words to use in google (but I also didn't ask on SO) and now I see I should look around graph topic :D (I was sure that something like this must exists already!).

Comment: It sounds a good info. If you can provide what a exact name of topic is, please let me know.

Answer (score 5):

**Base R:** `sort`ing `union` as `FUN=` in `combn`, then partly filling a matrix based on unique elements `u` and removing `duplicated` rows, and finally coercing `as.list`.

```
u <- Reduce(union, cbnl)  ## get unique elements

res <- combn(cbnl, 2, \(x) {
  if (length(intersect(x[[1]], x[[2]])) > 0) {
    union(x[[1]], x[[2]])
  } else {
    el(x)
  }
}, simplify=FALSE) |>
  unique() |>
  (\(x) sapply(x, \(i) replace(rep(NA, length(u)), match(i, u), i)))() |>
  (\(x) x[, !colSums(duplicated(x, MARGIN=1:2)) == nrow(x)])() |>
  (\(x) unname(lapply(as.list(as.data.frame(x)), \(x) x[!is.na(x)])))()

res
# [[1]]
# [1] "A" "B"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "C" "D" "E"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "F" "G"
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] "H" "I"
# 
# [[5]]
# [1] "J" "K"
```

**Note:**

```
> R.version.string
[1] "R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But expected result is not shown. I need to think how to get expected list in your way.

Comment: @kabocha Actually I missed a case handling, check update. I'm not yet sure, though, which rule  _exactly_ leads to your expected result?

Comment: Thank you very much. Almost completed. Just need to delete {C, D}, {D, E}, {C, E} because {C, D, E} includes them.

Comment: @kabocha Got ya, see update!

Comment: Thank you. Nearly completed but still {D, E} remains...

Comment: @kabocha Now it should work!

Comment: Finally, yes I could get expected result. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

I took a one line of code from @ThomasIsCoding and would like to show that we can achieve this using my package `dedupewider`.

```
library(dedupewider)
library(purrr)
library(magrittr)

cbnl <- list(
  c("A", "B"), c("B", "A"), c("C", "D"), c("E", "D"), c("F", "G"), c("H", "I"),
  c("J", "K"), c("I", "H"), c("K", "J"), c("G", "F"), c("D", "C"), c("E", "C"),
  c("D", "E"), c("C", "E")
)

cbnl_df <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, cbnl))

result <- dedupe_wide(cbnl_df, names(cbnl_df)) # it performs deduplication by connecting elements which are linked by transitive relation

result_list <- as.list(as.data.frame(t(result)))

result_list <- map(result_list, ~ .x[!is.na(.x)]) # remove NA
result_list
#> $V1
#> [1] "A" "B"
#> 
#> $V2
#> [1] "C" "E" "D"
#> 
#> $V3
#> [1] "F" "G"
#> 
#> $V4
#> [1] "H" "I"
#> 
#> $V5
#> [1] "J" "K"
```

A lot of steps are necessary, because list is an input and output, so with data.frame we would have less code than above.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My original data is data.table so your data.frame way is more preferable for me. I could get my expected result.

Comment: That's even better, because `dedupe_wide` internally uses `setDT` (at the end removes `data.table` class if wasn't present at the beginning) if needed, so you should get `data.table` object as returned value when `data.table` is an input.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all supporters' wonderful answers.

Let me post my own solution by base R as below;

```
cbnl <- list(
  c("A", "B"), c("B", "A"), c("C", "D"), c("E", "D"), c("F", "G"), c("H", "I"),
  c("J", "K"), c("I", "H"), c("K", "J"), c("G", "F"), c("D", "C"), c("E", "C"),
  c("D", "E"), c("C", "E")
)

repeat {
  # Get A Count Table
  tbl <- table(unlist(cbnl))
  # No Duplicated Items Then break Out
  if (length(tbl[tbl > 1]) == 0) { break }
  # Take A First Duplicated Item And Get the Index
  idx <- which(sapply(seq_len(length(cbnl)), function(i) {
    any(cbnl[[i]] == names(tbl[tbl > 1])[1])
  }))
  # Create New vector By Taking Union
  newvec <- sort(unique(unlist(cbnl[idx])))
  # Append newvec To cbnl And Remove Original vectors
  cbnl <- c(cbnl, list(newvec))[-idx]
}

cbnl
```

The result is

```
[[1]]
[1] "A" "B"

[[2]]
[1] "C" "D" "E"

[[3]]
[1] "F" "G"

[[4]]
[1] "H" "I"

[[5]]
[1] "J" "K"
```

Here is data.table version.

```
cbn <- data.table(
  item1 = c("A", "B", "C", "E", "F", "H", "J", "I", "K", "G", "D", "E", "D", "C"),
  item2 = c("B", "A", "D", "D", "G", "I", "K", "H", "J", "F", "C", "C", "E", "E")
)

repeat {
  # Get A Count Table
  tbl <- table(as.vector(as.matrix(cbn)))
  # No Duplicated Items Then break Out
  if (length(tbl[tbl > 1]) == 0) { break }
  # Take A First Duplicated Item And Get Row Numbers Where The Item Is Located
  idx <- which(cbn == names(tbl[tbl > 1])[1], arr.ind = TRUE)[, 1]
  # Create New Row By Taking Union
  newrow <- setDT(as.list(sort(unique(as.vector(as.matrix(cbn[idx]))))))
  names(newrow) <- paste0("item", seq_len(ncol(newrow)))
  # Append newrow To cbn And Remove Original Rows
  cbn <- rbindlist(l = list(cbn, newrow), use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE)[-idx]
}

cbn
```

This result is as below.

```
   item1 item2 item3
1:     A     B  <NA>
2:     C     D     E
3:     F     G  <NA>
4:     H     I  <NA>
5:     J     K  <NA>
```